# Why does the Scala compiler recognize a generic type twice

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism

Scala novice here with a confusing compiler error. It's not clear to me why the compiler recognizes the generic parametric type T in `msort[T]` as a different type from the argument type T in `(lt: (T, T) => Boolean)`.

```scala
def msort[T](xs: List[T])(lt: (T, T) => Boolean): List[T] = {
    val n = xs.length/2
    if (n == 0) xs
    else {
        def merge[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = 
            (xs, ys) match {
                case (Nil, _) => ys
                case (_, Nil) => xs
                case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => 
                    if (lt(x, y))
                        x :: merge(xs1, ys)
                    else
                        y :: merge(xs, ys1)
            }
        val (fst, snd) = xs splitAt n
        merge(msort(fst)(lt), msort(snd)(lt))
    }
}
```

[The issue is with line 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTFFw.png) when testing order of x and y `if (lt(x, y))`. I get 2 type mismatch errors but am not sure what went wrong.

```bash
[error] -- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: /..../src/main/scala/Main.scala:10:27 
[error] 10 |                    if (lt(x, y))
[error]    |                           ^
[error]    |                           Found:    (x : T)
[error]    |                           Required: T²
[error]    |
[error]    |                           where:    T  is a type in method merge
[error]    |                                     T² is a type in method msort
[error] -- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: /..../src/main/scala/Main.scala:10:30 
[error] 10 |                    if (lt(x, y))
[error]    |                              ^
[error]    |                              Found:    (y : T)
[error]    |                              Required: T²
[error]    |
[error]    |                              where:    T  is a type in method merge
[error]    |                                        T² is a type in method msort
[error] two errors found
```

***Dev Env***

```
Mac OsX
sbt.version=1.3.2
scalaVersion=2.13.1
```

Comment: BTW I think there would be some benefits to replace `(T, T) => Boolean` by `scala.math.Ordering[T]` (typeclass that provides `lt`)

Comment: great point @cchantep. Using `implicit ord: Ordering` helped leverage Scala's type inference for some good encapsulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type parameter `T` of inner method `merge` is shadowing the type parameter of the same name `T` of the outer method `msort`. Instead try removing the type parameter from `merge` like so

```
def msort[T](xs: List[T])(lt: (T, T) => Boolean): List[T] = {
  val n = xs.length/2
  if (n == 0) xs
  else {
    def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] =
      (xs, ys) match {
        case (Nil, _) => ys
        case (_, Nil) => xs
        case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
          if (lt(x, y))
            x :: merge(xs1, ys)
          else
            y :: merge(xs, ys1)
      }
    val (fst, snd) = xs splitAt n
    merge(msort(fst)(lt), msort(snd)(lt))
  }
}
```